# ARIMA model with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, arima

I have the following dataset `test_1`

```
Date    Frequency
0   2020-01-20  10
1   2020-01-21  2
2   2020-01-22  1
3   2020-01-23  10
4   2020-01-24  6
... ... ...
74  2020-04-04  7
75  2020-04-05  9
76  2020-04-06  8
77  2020-04-07  6
78  2020-04-08  1
```

where `Frequency` is a calculated column with the frequency of users by date.

I would like to predict the future trends and to do it I am considering an ARIMA model.
I have used this code

```
# fit model
model = ARIMA(test_1, order=(5,1,0))
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())
# plot residual errors
residuals = DataFrame(model_fit.resid)
residuals.plot()
pyplot.show()
residuals.plot(kind='kde')
pyplot.show()
print(residuals.describe())
```

but I have got this error: `ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).`

due to `model = ARIMA(test_1, order=(5,1,0))`.

Do you know what it means and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error states that `ARIMA` expects an array-like object, but you've passed a `DataFrame` instead.

This can be solved by passing the `test_1["Frequency"]` instead of just `test_1`. Also, I will fix some of the other things that I encountered in your code:

```
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot

# fit model
model = ARIMA(test_1["Frequency"], order=(5,1,0)) #<--- change this
model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
print(model_fit.summary())
# plot residual errors
residuals = pd.DataFrame(model_fit.resid)
residuals.plot(kind='kde')
print(residuals.describe())
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much Anwarvic. I have got this other error:  `----> 6 residuals = DataFrame(model_fit.resid)
      7 residuals.plot()
      8 pyplot.show()

NameError: name 'DataFrame' is not defined` . Do you think is anything related to the previous error?